# Passing data from multiple forms/ Array of same form flask wtforms python

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am trying to make a flask application that pulls questions from a sqlite database and then lets you submit a score and comment for each question. I am having trouble understanding how to generate the forms for all of the questions and being able to pass the data from the forms back to my flask app. My current web page looks like this:

[Current Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB7uT.png)

The html file I am using to generate this looks like this:

**record.html**

```
<doctype html="">
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method="post">
  <table>
    {% for key, value in form_dict.items() %}
        <TR>
          {% set x = key[4:]|int %}
          <TD class="c1">{{ question_list[x-1] }}</TD>
          <TD class="c1">{{ key }}</TD>
          <TD class="c2">{{ render_field(value.score) }}</TD>
          <TD class="c3">{{ render_field(value.comment) }}</TD>
        </TR>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p></form>
</doctype>
```

And the python/flask code looks like this:

```
class Record_Form(Form):

    score_choices = [('0.00', '0.00'),
                     ('0.25', '0.25'),
                     ('0.50','0.50'),
                     ('0.75','0.75'),
                     ('1.00','1.00')]
    score = SelectField('Score', choices=score_choices)
    comment = StringField('Comment')
    owner = StringField('Owner')

@app.route('/record/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_record(id):
    form = Record_Form(request.form)
    question_list_qry = Question.query.all()
    question_list = []
    question_ids_list = []
    for i in question_list_qry:
        question_list.append(i.question)
        question_ids_list.append(i.id)

    form_dict={}
    for id in question_ids_list:
        form_dict[f'form{id}'] = Record_Form(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():

        print(form_dict['form1'].score.data)
        print(form_dict['form2'].score.data)
        print(form_dict['form3'].score.data)

        print(form_dict['form1'].comment.data)
        print(form_dict['form2'].comment.data)
        print(form_dict['form3'].comment.data)

        return redirect('/')
    return render_template('record.html', question_list=question_list, form_dict=form_dict)
```

Currently, if I go into my flask app and submit three different scores and three different comments in the first three questions. The resulting output is only from the "form1".

[Three different scores and comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNCiA.png)

But this is the output I get:

```
0.25
0.25
0.25
Dog
Dog
Dog
```

What am I doing incorrectly? I think it has something to do with form.validate but I am not sure.

Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<form method="post">
  <table>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 1</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form1</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 2</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form2</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 3</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form3</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 4</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form4</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 5</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form5</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 6</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form6</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 7</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form7</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 8</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form8</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 9</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form9</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 10</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form10</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 11</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form11</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>

          <TD class="c1">Question 12</TD>
          <TD class="c1">form12</TD>
          <TD class="c2">
    <dt><label for="score">Score</label>
    </dt><dd><select id="score" name="score"><option value="0.00">0.00</option><option value="0.25">0.25</option><option value="0.50">0.50</option><option value="0.75">0.75</option><option value="1.00">1.00</option></select>

    </dd>
</TD>
          <TD class="c3">
    <dt><label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </dt><dd><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="">

    </dd>
</TD>
        </TR>

  </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p></form>
</doctype>
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with reused variable name `id` in the for loop

Comment: Which for loop and what variable name ```id```? I don't have a variable named ```id```.

Comment: ```for id in question_ids_list:
        form_dict[f'form{id}'] = Record_Form(request.form)```

Comment: Is ```id``` actually a variable in this context? I could change it to ```for milkshake in question_ids_list: form_dict[f'form{milkshake}'] = Record_Form(request.form)``` and it  gives me the same output.

Comment: Can you upload the `html` source for your webpage?

Comment: It's in the original question, its record.html.

Comment: I meant the actual rendered webpage nad not the templet. Press `Ctrl+U` in the browser.

Comment: See edits, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have the same `name` for all `select` tags and all `input` tags. You need to use different names for them if all of them are in the same field, or else they will be overwritten by each other.

**record.html**

```
<doctype html="">
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method="post">
  <table>
    {% for key, value in form_dict.items() %}
        <TR>
          {% set x = key[4:]|int %}
          <TD class="c1">{{ question_list[x-1] }}</TD>
          <TD class="c1">{{ key }}</TD>
          <TD class="c2">{{ render_field(value.score, name='score'+str(x)) }}</TD>
          <TD class="c3">{{ render_field(value.comment, name='comment'+str(x)) }}</TD>
        </TR>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p></form>
</doctype>
```

You also need to change your server code like this:

```
form_dict['form1']['score1']
form_dict['form2']['score2']
form_dict['form3']['score3']
```

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't get this to work. I don't think the render_field function lets you create names like that in flask, but I can't find good documentation for it.

Comment: This is what I found: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/